# Php write the results to file, But I failed to write it

Tags: php, file-permissions

```
$a1=array(
"channelOne"=>"-45",
"channelTwo"=>"-100",
"channelThree"=>"-20"

);

$a2=array(
"channelOne"=>"-48",
"channelTwo"=>"-90",
"channelThree"=>"-22"
);

$diff = array_map(
    function ($a1, $a2)
    {
        return abs($a1-$a2);
    }, $a1,$a2
);
print_r($diff);


$ourFileName = "testFile.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

I tried to write the results to file. But I failed to do it. can someone help me here?

Warning: fopen(testFile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: `Permission denied`… then check your write permissions on the specific directory??

Comment: The www-data group most likely doesn't have access to the file in question. You could fix that by saying `chgrp www-data file.txt` or `chmod 0777 file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission to do this. Probably the webserver user  doesn't have write permission
 You should check which directory are you. `get_cwd()` and check the permissions.

Comment: how should I do to fix the problem ? I run it on my local server

Comment: @HaonanYang if it is linux ensure you have chmod 0777 if windows iis make sure you have iusr full access security

Comment: Try to add fwrite($ourFileHandle, print_r($diff,1)); before the fclose()